# How is ~CH derived in paraconsistent set theory?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, paraconsistency

[This question on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/134427/a-question-about-paraconsistent-set-theory-and-the-continuum-hypothesis) has been left unanswered. The respondents pointed mainly towards ["Transfinite Numbers in Paraconsistent Set Theory"](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/review-of-symbolic-logic/article/abs/transfinite-numbers-in-paraconsistent-set-theory/7084AB545445A0CCFCBACEB3FEC86FE1), an article to which I don't have access. Does anyone here know how the derivation proceeds? I'm not quite at a point in my life where I am ready to accept paraconsistency or dialetheias just to have an answer to CH, but just in case...

Comment: You do not need dialetheias to settle CH, constructibility implies GCH, and [Martin's maximum](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~alopez-o/math-faq/mathtext/node37.html) implies 2^ℵ0 = ℵ2, for example.

Comment: Maybe I have bad intuitions, but my intuition says that a deduction from paraconsistent set theory would be more "plausible" than one from the axiom of constructibility (which measurable cardinals tell against anyway?) or the principle of Martin's maximum. To be totally honest, I don't have a good grasp of even half the mathematics involved, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the basis of a full axiom of comprehension, Weber shows that there is a set of all sets, which he denotes V, and a set of all ordinals, which he denotes On. He uses von Neumann’s definition of a cardinal as the smallest ordinal equinumerous with the set. From this it follows that On is itself a cardinal number, since it is the least of its size. In fact, On is the cardinal of V. Since all cardinals are ordinals, all cardinals are less than On. Hence by existential generalization:

> ∃x∀y(|y| < |x|)

And thence:

> ∀y∃x(|y| < |x|)

Since |ω| := ℵ<sub>0</sub> by definition, it follows that ∃y(ℵ<sub>0</sub> < y). This shows that there are uncountable cardinals and establishes that there are distinctive orders of infinity.

Weber then constructs a counterexample to GCH as follows (p. 90):

> In a similar vein, a cardinal λ is said to be inaccessible if for
> every κ < λ, also 2<sup>κ</sup> < λ. The existence of inaccessible cardinals is
> unprovable in ZFC. But, almost trivially, On is such a cardinal: For κ
> < On, also 2<sup>κ</sup> < On, because On is the biggest. Therefore inaccessible
> cardinals exist.
>
> Finally, the generalized continuum hypothesis GCH conjectures for all
> cardinals κ, λ that ￢(κ < λ < |P(κ)|). The GCH evidently fails at On,
> as the cardinal On provides a counterexample. Assuming that On <
> |P(On)|, still we would have (by the Burali–Forti contradiction) that
> On < On < |P(On)|. Then again, this does not rule out the GCH in
> general; in fact, an instance of GCH holds at On. Let λ be a cardinal
> On < λ < |P(On)|. Being a cardinal, ￢(On < λ), since all cardinals are
> members of, and less than, On. Thus ￢(On < λ < |P(On)|). In fact,
> further assuming that On = On + 1 obtains via the Schröder–Bernstein
> theorem, and that On = ℵ<sub>On</sub>, then by existential generalization,
>
> ∃α(2<sup>ℵ<sub>α</sub></sup> = ℵ<sub>α+1</sub>).

Comment: That's so clever and weird. Unfortunately, it seems to be about the GCH more than the CH. I can live with a GCH failure somewhere in transfinite arithmetic; in fact I have to, as the "model" I am working on unexpectedly turned out to encode a GCH failure at the first fixed point of the aleph function.

Comment: It is interesting that Weber uses proof by contradiction. Just to clarify, only ￢GCH is provable, it is not the case that GCH is also provable and hence a dialetheia, right?

Comment: I feel like the argument equivocates when it gets to showing that "an instance of GCH holds at On." On + 1 is cardinally equivalent to On like ω & ω+1 would be to each other, so if P(On) = On and On = On + 1, Weber isn't showing that P(On) is equal to the cardinal but only the ordinal successor of On (which he doesn't seem to have???).